# SQL with buckets for columns

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to write a `sql` query to columns that represents buckets of data :

For example, if my data is:

```
title | value
A     | 1.2
A     | 2.3
B     | 0.5
B     | 0.8
B     | 1.7
```

And I'm want my output to look like:

```
title | count(0-1) | count(1-2) | count(2+)
A     | 0          | 1          | 1
B     | 2          | 1          | 0
```

I was able to get this result by writing multiple queries that, for example,  included:

```
WHERE value >= 0 AND value < 1
```

to get a table that represented each bucket, then merged the tables.  My issue is that I'm querying a very large database, so running multiple queries takes a long time.

Is there an automatic way to do this in a sql query?

Comment: You could use `View`s, and optimize the database with `indices`

Comment: `running multiple queries takes a long time.` Are you sure less queries = more speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
select title, 
       sum(case when value >= 0 and value < 1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when value >= 1 and value < 2 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when value >= 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
from table t
group by title'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select title,
       sum(case when value >= 0 and value < 1 then 1 else 0 end) as bucket_0_1,
       sum(case when value >= 1 and value < 2 then 1 else 0 end) as bucket_1_2,
       sum(case when value >= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as bucket_2pl
from t
group by title;
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select sum( case when value>=0 and value<1 then 1 else 0 end )
as b_0_1',
sum( case when value>=1 and value<2 then 1 else 0 end )as b_1_2,
sum( case when value>2 then 1 else 0 end ) as b_2 ,tittle
from t group by title
```